# How can I render to a texture?

Tags: rendering, game-engine

thank you for reading this, and hopefully thank you for answering, I am using blender 2.7 and it is great but I am having trouble using the render to texture script (provided in this video [ https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HgXAv9csJu0 ]) (Please note I am not asking for anyone to do the tutorial and provide feed back, I am asking for anyone that has a render to texture script or knows of a tutorial that will work on blender 2.7 and is willing to share the script or tutorial, to please share any helpful material. This youtube video serve to prove the script of which did not work in 2.7

I have followed this video to the letter in a new blend, and still the script did not work.

I need a render to texture script that works, and I can't use alternates for my mini map because I need to use the RTT for other features, thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a specific tutorial and script not packaged with Blender.

Comment: Please, you can't expect volunteer people like us to go through a tutorial trying to reproduce your issue. Please only come to us with specific questions.

Comment: I understand the mistake, its not able a tutorial, the tutorial show the script that did not work, thus not allow the script to be repeated, I am actually only asking for a way to render to texture, something that has been an issue for me for 3 month and has multiple uses. I also do not expect people to go out of there way to try the tutorial, I am just try to appeal to person who has a script on hand. Sorry if this question has made you uncomfortable in any but that was not my intesion

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question. As it is now it is more suitable to ask the author of the tutorial. Working code is included in the API documentation of VideoTexture (it is not the best code, but it works)

Comment: I will try that, I am sorry for the cofussion I will also look throw the API